# MySQL Query returning blank key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL Query which works fine except the field `rnd_key` is returned as `null` despite it having values. If I run a normal query without the join then the key is returned.

```
SELECT *, SUM(time_duration) as total_time
FROM rnd
LEFT JOIN time ON rnd.rnd_key = time.rnd_key
WHERE rnd.rnd_owner = $eng AND rnd.rnd_status != 90 
          AND (rnd.rnd_status != 80 OR rnd.rnd_status > '".$ninetyDate."')
GROUP BY rnd.rnd_key
```

Thanks

Comment: does the table `time` have any rows with `rnd_key` as null?

Comment: yes there are several

Comment: try two things: first: try right join, another thing is try to give each of rnd_key columns diffrent alias names. duplicated names may cause such problem

Comment: Excellent - changing the name of the column in the time table worked - thanks

Comment: @Mohammad Ahmad -- post your comment as an Answer.  The user can Accept it -- good for all of us.

Answer (score 1):

try two things:

First: try RIGHT JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

Second: try to give each of rnd_key columns diffrent alias names. duplicated names may cause such problem